# Elements of double dual that are not evaluation maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

I'm revising some of my notes and I stumbled across this question. Let $V = F^\infty$, the set of sequences in a field with finite support, and let the evaluation map $E : V \rightarrow V^{**}$ be defined as $E(v)(f) = f(v)$ with $ f \in V^*$. It is easy to show that $E$ is injective and I know that it is not surjective, but I cannot seem to find any examples of elements in $V^{**}$ that are not mapped to by $E$ for some element in the domain.

I know that this would need some kind of the axiom of choice, but am lost as to how to proceed.

I would appreciate any and help in finding an example of this!

Comment: The *general* statement about $V \not\cong V^*$ when $V$ is infinite-dimensional needs the axiom of choice.  That does not mean a *specific example* needs the axiom of choice.  See the recent post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757844/proof-verification-polynomials-mathbb-rx-are-a-vector-space-that-is-not-is.  Your vector space $F^\infty$ (sequences with finite support) is essentially the same as the example $F[X]$ on that page, with $F = \mathbf R$.

Comment: That statement is regarding the 'single' dual space. I was interested in the double dual, so I can't really see the connection to that question.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Why do you think an example has to be expressible in a concrete way when you intend to involve the axiom of choice?  That is a nonconstructive axiom.  For instance, in the countable direct product of fields $\prod_{n \geq 1} F$, the proper ideal $\bigoplus_{n \geq 1} F$ of sequences with finite support has to be contained in a maximal ideal by the axiom of choice, but it is unrealistic to expect to see an actual down-to-earth example of such a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 1):

We use AC in the following way: for $V_1<V_2$ $F$-vectorspaces, any element of $V_1^\vee$ can be extended to an element of $V_2^\vee$. (*Proof*: partially order the extensions by domain inclusion and pick a maximal $f$ by Zorn.  If $\operatorname{dom}f\neq V_2$ you can clearly make an extension by pick some $v\notin\operatorname{dom}f$ and send it to say $0\in F$, extending $f$ to a bigger domain $\operatorname{dom}f\oplus Fv$, contradiction.)

So we can declare what our element $\beta\in V^{\vee\vee}$ does:  it sends $e_i^*$ to $0$ for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$, and it sends the element $\phi\in V^{\vee}$, $\phi((a_i))=\sum a_i$ (note $(a_i)\in V$ has finite support, so this sum makes sense) to $1\in F$.  This $\beta$ defines an element of $[(1,1,1,\dots)F\oplus\bigoplus^\infty F]^\vee$ and so we can extend to some $\tilde\beta\in V^{\vee\vee}$.  This $\tilde\beta$ is not in the image of the natural embedding $j\colon V\to V^{\vee\vee}$ because any element of $j(V)$ which vanishes on $e_i^*$ must be zero.

Comment: This example is really interesting! I certainly would not be able to come up with this. Would there perhaps be a simpler argument to show $E$ (the evaluation map defined in the question) is not surjective?